# How to do mouseover function in selenium webdriver using javascript

Tags: java, frameworks, selenium-webdriver

I need to do mouseover function using JavaScript, I have tried the below code am not getting any error but mouseover function not happening.

```
      WebElement Mainmenu=_driver.findElement(By.xpath(locatorvalue[0]));
    String strJavaScript = "var element = arguments[0];"
            + "var mouseEventObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');"
            + "mouseEventObj.initEvent( 'mouseover', true, true );"
            + "element.dispatchEvent(mouseEventObj);";
     JavascriptExecutor js =  (JavascriptExecutor) _driver;
     js.executeScript(strJavaScript, Mainmenu);
```

Comment: You can use actions class to perform mouse related activities.

Comment: already i used action class it not working in all browsers and all application,Thats y am going through javascript

Comment: String javaScript = "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" + "evObj.initMouseEvent(\"mouseover\",true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);"
         + "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);";
         ((JavascriptExecutor) Driver.driver).executeScript(javaScript, element);                     This should work. Give it a try.

Comment: no boss its not working

Comment: Can you give use the web-page you're trying to work on so that we can better understand what "not working" means?

Comment: http://delphi.com/ this is the application try

Comment: @Raghu Can you provide the browser name and version and webdriver version for which the Action class is not working for mouseover?

Comment: @HemChe IE-8, Selenium webdriver 2.35

Comment: @Raghu For IE9 real cursor must be OUTSIDE the browser window. Did you try this while using Actions class ?

Answer (score 2):

```
public void click(WebElement a,WebElement b)
{
    try 
     {
         String mouseOverScript = "if(document.createEvent){var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');evObj.initEvent('mouseover',true, false); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);} else if(document.createEventObject) { arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover');}";
         ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(mouseOverScript,a);
         Thread.sleep(1000);
         ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(mouseOverScript,b);
         Thread.sleep(1000);
         ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();",b);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$('element_selector').hover();");
```

Hope this will help